# How to remove the sites url from the link

Tags: jquery

I'm using ajax for my [blog](http://www.axinkhabar.com/) and need to change the title when the next page is loaded.

I'm trying to do this by getting the url from the next's link and add it to the title.
Now I just need to remove the site's url for example from this url:
www.mysite.com/page/2

I only need to target after the last slash
Only: 2

By using this after clicking on the next page I target the whole url:

```
var LinkTitle = jQuery(this).attr('href');
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also work:

```
url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

There are obviously a lot of ways to do it (regex, `replace()`, `split()`, etc.). I suggest going on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) and seeing which is the quickest on most browsers, and doing that. And maybe you can report those results on here so future people who visit the question can take advantage of that info as well.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me, the same goes with the other answers. Can you please take a look here and let me know how should I implement your code to it? http://www.axinkhabar.com/wp-content/themes/edge131/js/ajax-pages.js

Comment: @Webzyy: In your case, just use my code after `var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');`. Of course, you need to change the variable name from `url` to `link` as per your implementation.

Comment: @Webzyy: I'm not sure what's going on with `jQuery(navi).load(link+(' .wp-pagenavi'));` though. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I did this before but doesn't work please recheck.

Comment: .wp-pagenavi is outside the section where the ajax loads in the page, that calls .wp-pagenavi too to be added...

Comment: Webzyy: Log the initial value of `link` after the `attr()` call. And then log the value that is returned by `link = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`. Because I've tested this in Node.js using real URLs and it works.

Comment: I've tried but the var link creates a conflict when it's called in history: `window.history.pushState("object or string", link, link);` the second var link only works, which targets the address bar, the middle one doesn't work, any ideas why?

Comment: Webzyy: The first `link` is setting a currently unimplemented title parameter, while the second `link` is the parameter that sets the address bar URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/#section_6

Comment: Right, however the second var link is affecting the last link in the window.history, it changes the url based on your code and the title still remains the same.              
`var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            var link = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            window.history.pushState("object or string", link , link);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13850/discussion-between-lese-majeste-and-webzyy)

Answer (score 3):

```
var myHref = this.href.split('/');
var LinkTitle = myHref[myHref.length-1];
```

Comment: and if page will be 28? or 966?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to obtain an array and get its last element.

```
arr = LinkTitle.split("/");
yourTitle = arr[arr.length-1];
```